# What is the difference between the .mean() and the .avg() methods?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, average, mean, median

Currently, I am working with PySpark to analyze some data. I have a CSV file with Payroll data in it.
I want to know what Job has the best pay. To do that I need the median() because I want to know the average.

The methods for `groupBy` in Pyspark are these:
`agg`, `avg`, `count`, `max`, `mean`, `min`, `pivot`, `sum`

When I try the `.mean()` method it looks like this:

```py
mean_pay_data = reduced_data.groupBy("JOB_TITLE").mean("REGULAR_PAY")
mean_pay_data.show(3)

# +--------------------+-----------------+
# |           JOB_TITLE| avg(REGULAR_PAY)|
# +--------------------+-----------------+
# |SENIOR SECURITY O...|59818.79285751433|
# |SENIOR TRAFFIC SU...| 72116.8394540951|
# |AIR CONDITIONING ...|98415.21726190476|
# +--------------------+-----------------+
```

Here is what it looks like with the `.avg()` method:

```py
average_pay_data = reduced_data.groupBy("JOB_TITLE").avg("REGULAR_PAY")
average_pay_data.show(3)

# +--------------------+-----------------+
# |           JOB_TITLE| avg(REGULAR_PAY)|
# +--------------------+-----------------+
# |SENIOR SECURITY O...|59818.79285751433|
# |SENIOR TRAFFIC SU...| 72116.8394540951|
# |AIR CONDITIONING ...|98415.21726190476|
# +--------------------+-----------------+
```

They return the exact same values. What's the difference between `mean()` and `avg()`?

I also want to find the median, so that one person doesn't have too much of an impact.
Since there is no *`median()`* method in PySpark I don't know what to do here.

Comment: there *is* a median method in pyspark. see [`percentile_approx`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.percentile_approx.html#pyspark-sql-functions-percentile-approx). as for `mean` and `avg` - they're same. see [func list](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/functions.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both [`avg`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.avg.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.avg) and [`mean`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.mean.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.mean) documentation tell this:

> `mean()` is an alias for `avg()`

Both of these functions are identical. Both names are needed, so that developers coming from different backgrounds would feel comfortable.

Regarding the median:

- Approximate (efficient) median: `F.expr('percentile_approx(col_name, .5) over()')`
- Accurate (inefficient) median: `F.expr('percentile(col_name, .5) over()')`